# How to fix vscode GnuCOBOL setup "configuration error: default.conf: No such file or directory"

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnucobol

[image: vscode error message]

we are using cobol now, but this config error keeps on appearing and I do not know how to fix this thing. Any help would really mean alot. (Just a beginner and trying to learn vscode)

Comment: IS there anything "open" then please comment in the answer, if not mark the answer as "accepted = works best for me" - see https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late, but perhaps worth it. Currently there is a `cobenv.bat` or `.sh` (if you are on linux). The whole path to the file may differ for me is this:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cobenv.cmd
```

You'll notice that if you execute the file and run the compiler everything works fine, but once you close that bash the error shows up again.

That's because the scope of those variables was just that session. You may execute it every time you run the compiler or you can make those variables to persist on your system. In my case I did the later, modifying `cobenv.cmd`

But not those lines with the variable `PATH`.

So this lines, i.e., whenever we encounter this same three variables. For instance, after a certain `if` in that file we encounter:

```
  setx "COB_LIBRARY_PATH" "%MINGW_ROOT_PATH%lib\gnucobol%COB_LIBRARY_PATH%"
  setx "COB_COPY_DIR" "%MINGW_ROOT_PATH%share\gnucobol\copy"
  setx "COB_CONFIG_DIR" "%MINGW_ROOT_PATH%share\gnucobol\config"
```

Default value: `set`.

New value: `setx`.

Delete the `=` to comply with the correct syntax. Check the compiler with different new session.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error:

> /mingw/share/gnucobol/config\default.conf: No such file or directory

Use the `-conf` option:

```
$con = $HOME + "\gnucobol\config\default.conf"
cobc -v $cbl -I $lcop -conf="$con" -x -o $exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This message is only presented in vscode's Terminal after you've entered a command there, it is actually not related to vscode.

The "common" way with vscode would be to create a vscode task for the compilation and configure a problem matcher, too, so vscode is able to parse the messages. For details see vscode docs "[Integrate with External Tools via Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)".

As the message is coming from the GnuCOBOL compiler it may be reasonable to check in its discussion board, which also includes a note [how to use your setup of vscode with GnuCOBOL MinGW package](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/cobol/thread/efbb216fc0/), this would be your starting point, assuming `D:\COBOL` is the place where you have your sources (and this is the alos the workspaceFolder as in your screenshot), `D:\COBOL\copy` where your copybook reside and `D:\GnuCOBOL` where the MinGW package is:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "GnuCOBOL - cobc (compile single file)",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cobc",
            "args": [
                "-I${workspaceFolder}\\copy",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$gnucobol3-cobc",
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "COB_CFLAGS": "-I\"D:\\GnuCOBOL\\include\"",
                    "COB_CONFIG_DIR": "D:\\GnuCOBOL\\config",
                    "COB_COPY_DIR": "D:\\GnuCOBOL\\copy",
                    "COB_LDFLAGS": "-L\"D:\\GnuCOBOL\\lib\"",
                    "COB_LIBRARY_PATH": "D:\\GnuCOBOL\\extras",
                    "PATH": "D:\\GnuCOBOL\\bin:${env:PATH}"
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of directly calling `cobc` you could also call `cobc.bat` or similar, then create it with all your default options set there (or, if you use the official mingw packages, just call the `set_env.cmd`) then call the compiler.

Concerning "how to fix that message" - make sure you have the "config" directory of GnuCOBOL and have `COB_CONFIG_DIR` set to it either in the task definition or outside of vscode (for example by starting vscode from the "Developer prompt for GnuCOBOL MinGW" (which is the set_env.cmd distributed with it).